# Jquery code to filter records. best technique/code

Tags: jquery

here is my code... all i am trying to do is to filter using jquery thru a "dataset"  of records i am pulling from a database.

this is my code but it's terribly unefficient.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#descriptionField").bind('keyup',function(e){
        var filter = $(this).val();
        if(filter)
        {
            $("#list").find("a:not(:contains(" + filter + "))").parent().slideUp();
            $("#list").find("a:contains(" + filter + ")").parent().slideDown();
        }
   });
 });
 </script>
```

Comment: remove the slideUp and slideDown functionality, and add a throttle so that it doesn't run on EVERY keyup.

Comment: This belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Just wondering why this wasn't moved and instead closed?

Answer (score 1):

You can always cache selections that get used multiple times:

```
$(function(){
   var $A = $('#list').find('a');
   $("#descriptionField").bind('keyup',function(e){
        var filter = this.value;
        if(filter.length > 0)
        {
            $A.filter(":not(:contains(" + filter + "))").parent().hide();
            $A.filter(":contains(" + filter + ")").parent().show();
        }
   });
});
```

I removed the animated `slideDown()` and `slideUp()` function calls for the less CPU intensive `show()` and `hide()`. Also instead of using jQuery to get the value of the input, I used `this.value` which should be a little faster.

Instead of using the pseudo selectors of `:not()` and `:contains()` you could use `filter()` to do this:

```
$(function(){
   var $A = $('#list').find('a');
   $("#descriptionField").bind('keyup',function(e){
        var filter = this.value;
        if(filter.length > 0)
        {
            $A.filter(function () {
                return ($(this).text().indexOf(filter) === -1)
            }).parent().hide();
            $A.filter(function () {
                return ($(this).text().indexOf(filter) > -1)
            }).parent().show();
        }
   });
});
```

Here is a jsperf to show the performance increase when using `.filter()` over `:contains()`: http://jsperf.com/jquery-contains-vs-filter

Comment: Another caching thing you could do is create an object outside of the event binding that stores previously used filter keywords. If the filter has already been done, show and hide using the selected elements from that filter.

Comment: I replaced slideUp and down for show and hide. very fast. just what we needed it. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: @Tony You're welcome. If you change to the `.filter()` approach you'll get another bump in performance.